# Geometry Nodes: How to shrinkwrap instanced planes around the object they were distributed on?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, shrinkwrap, surface-deform

[image: Planes distributed on surface of object, they are flat and don't deform to match the curvature of the object beneath]

I am trying to make the vertices of the planes wrap around the pig's body. The planes themselves already stick to the body and are oriented along the normals of the pig but i want them to deform to fit the shape better. I tried using the raycast node to implement a sort of shrinkwrap effect but it seems the raycast node cannot be used with geometry which was created in the node tree (the planes) as the source position. Can the raycast node somehow be worked with to allow for my use-case or is there another way of making the planes deform to wrap around the pig?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this can be achieved as seen below with the simulation nodes. I came across the solution through a Default Cube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mnSg5iOS4QU

I hope this answer helps someone else who is trying to get this effect :) [image: Node setup and results]